# Are you entitled to a copy of your employment background check?

Tags: canada, employment

In Ontario, Canada,  are you entitled to a copy of your employment background check? Does it matter of you were offered the job or not? Is there a time limit? 
Background check consists of reference check,  criminal record and credit history.

Comment: You're not going to find out if you got a bad reference, if that's what you're looking for. I can't recall specifics, but AFAIK it's illegal for employers to prevent you from getting another job. So, if a potential employer called a reference and the reference said "he's garbage, don't hire him." they're not gonna rat eachother out.

If it's criminal record that you want a copy of, that cost the employer money and its theirs. If you want one, go to a local OPP station and pay the $40 to get yourself a copy.

Comment: I'm not entirely correct on the points about references. More here: http://career-advice.monster.ca/job-interview/interview-preparation/employment-law-asking-for-reference-canada/article.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly apply for your own background check and pay the appropriate fee for it. You are not entitled to the one the prospective employer bought and paid for; they paid for it, it belongs to them.